# How can I change an Rg.Plugins popup template to be coded in C#

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have created a Popup in Xamarin Forms using Rg.Plugins.Popup.  Now I would like to change that popup to C# but I don't know how I can do this. Can anyone offer some words of advice?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<pages:PopupPage
    x:Class="Test.Templates.BaseBottomSheet"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:animations="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Animations;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
    xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
    x:Name="this"
    CloseWhenBackgroundIsClicked="True">
    <pages:PopupPage.Animation>
        <animations:MoveAnimation
            HasBackgroundAnimation="True"
            PositionIn="Bottom"
            PositionOut="Bottom" />
    </pages:PopupPage.Animation>
    <pages:PopupPage.Content>
    <Frame
        BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource BottomSheetBackgroundColor}"
        CornerRadius="{DynamicResource BottomSheetCornerRadius}"
        HasShadow="False"
        Margin="{OnPlatform Android='20,0,20,0',
                            iOS='20,0,20,30'}"
        Padding="20"
        VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand">
        <ContentView Content="{Binding Source={x:Reference this}, Path=InnerContent}" />
    </Frame>
</pages:PopupPage.Content>
</pages:PopupPage>
```

Here is the backing C# that I am using:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Test.Templates
{
    [ContentProperty(nameof(InnerContent))]
    public partial class BaseBottomSheet : Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages.PopupPage
    {
        public BaseBottomSheet()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = this;
        }

        public static readonly BindableProperty InnerContentProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(InnerContent), typeof(View), typeof(BaseBottomSheet));

        public View InnerContent
        {
            get => (View)this.GetValue(InnerContentProperty);
            set => this.SetValue(InnerContentProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
```

**Code update based on Lucas's answer:**

```
public class BaseBottomSheet2 : Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages.PopupPage
{
    public BaseBottomSheet2()
    {
        BindingContext = this;

        this.CloseWhenBackgroundIsClicked = true;

        Animation = new Rg.Plugins.Popup.Animations.MoveAnimation()
        {

            HasBackgroundAnimation = true,
            PositionIn = MoveAnimationOptions.Bottom,
            PositionOut = MoveAnimationOptions.Bottom,
            DurationIn = 200,
            DurationOut = 200,
            EasingIn = Easing.SinOut,
            EasingOut = Easing.SinIn
        };

        ContentView content = new ContentView();
        content.SetBinding(ContentView.ContentProperty, "InnerContent");

        Content = new Frame()
        {
            BackgroundColor = Color.Red,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.EndAndExpand,
            Padding = 20,
            Content = content,
        };
        //Content.SetDynamicResource(Frame.BackgroundColorProperty, "BottomSheetBackgroundColor");
        //Content.SetDynamicResource(Frame.CornerRadiusProperty, "BottomSheetCornerRadius");
        //if (App.devIsIOS)
        //    Content.Margin = new Thickness(20, 0, 20, 30);
        //else
        //    Content.Margin = new Thickness(20, 0, 20, 0);
    }


    public static readonly BindableProperty InnerContentProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(InnerContent), typeof(View), typeof(BaseBottomSheet2));

    public View InnerContent
    {
        get => (View)this.GetValue(InnerContentProperty);
        set => this.SetValue(InnerContentProperty, value);
    }


}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want to define the child elements in code behind instead of in xaml ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check the following code

```
using Rg.Plugins.Popup.Enums;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace xxx
{
    public class BaseBottomSheet : Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages.PopupPage
    {
        public BaseBottomSheet()
        {
            BindingContext = this;

            this.CloseWhenBackgroundIsClicked = true;

            Animation = new Rg.Plugins.Popup.Animations.MoveAnimation() {

                HasBackgroundAnimation = true,
                PositionIn = MoveAnimationOptions.Bottom,
                PositionOut = MoveAnimationOptions.Bottom,

            };


            ContentView content = new ContentView();
            content.SetBinding(ContentView.ContentProperty, "InnerContent");

            Content = new Frame() {

                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.EndAndExpand,

                Content = content,

            };


        }


        public static readonly BindableProperty InnerContentProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(InnerContent), typeof(View), typeof(BaseBottomSheet));

        public View InnerContent
        {
            get => (View)this.GetValue(InnerContentProperty);
            set => this.SetValue(InnerContentProperty, value);
        }

       
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Lucas,  I tried this, made a small change by adding: BackgroundColor = Color.Red to the Frame but I notice it does not seem to be showing up. Any ideas? Whatever I add to the frame properties doesn't show.

Comment: Try to set the height of the frame

Comment: It works  fine on my side , so you could share your sample .

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention to you but the contents appear in the frame. I will add the full code that I have.

Comment: You need to set the bgColor of the ContentView .

Comment: I am just trying to make it visible. I will show you what the result looks like now. As you can see it doesn't show the color or have any padding. I also uncommented the margins and it still shows no margin. Note I also updated the Xaml in the question to show you how it was originally.  For this question I had simplified it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224785/discussion-between-lucas-zhang-msft-and-alan2).